# How Do You Secure API Using JWT To Prevent Fake Websites

Tags: api, jwt, client

I understand JWT can be used to authenticate a user but not much info seems to available on how you can secure the connection between frontend and backend api to ensure the website is not a fake duplicated used to lure users and steal their creds.

Maybe I'm just not wording my searches properly or understanding the topic, but how would you ensure that the client trying to connect to your API backend is authorized to and denied if it's not, even if the correct creds are used?  This is for JWT.

I know it can be secured using API keys but this question is specific to JWT.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a great deal you can do against social engineering attacks. If data is sensitive then giving users regular warnings about how people might try to trick them with fake websites is fairly common.

Wikipedia lists a number of techniques that can be used to [customise the UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing#Augmenting_password_logins) to make it easier for the user to recognise that they are on the right site.

[2 factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing#Multi-factor_authentication) can also help. While incorrect credentials could result in a token being passed to the attacker (allowing them access to the site), it will expire after whatever time limit you put on it and they will need to refresh it or be unable to reuse the password (since they won't have the new 2FA code).

You can also monitor for logins from large numbers of different users from the same IP address.